# Searching and exporting pattern using grep, awk or sed over multiple lines

Tags: awk, sed, scripting, grep, pattern-matching

First of all, I'm no programmer but chemist. I started doing quantum-chemistry calculations and I need to process data in files that are 1M lines long. I've tried solutions found here but none of them matched the need. Problem is that output file from the computation is looking like this

> 43718,0.0040389517\Am,-1.7885800013,-0.6239343718,-0.0040389517\Versi
>    on=AM64L-G09RevD.01\State=13-AU\HF=-4237.9263963\S2=43.283985\S2-1=0.\
>    S2A=42.176337\RMSD=5.586e-09\RMSF=2.812e-05\Dipole=0.,0.,0.\Quadrupole

or this

> 63732,-2.373882,2.364348\C,0,1.172319,-2.404467,3.15907\La,0,1.953277,
>    0.,0.\La,0,-1.953277,0.,0.\Version=AM64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-AG\HF=-39
>    18.0496979\RMSD=3.915e-09\Dipole=0.,0.,0.\Quadrupole=12.1772596,-7.248

The parameters are divided by backslashes, but can be separated on two lines.
What I'm looking for is script, that would find `HF=XXXX.XXXXX`and print it. For the two examples above it should find and print

> HF=-4237.9263963
>
> HF=-3918.0496979

Is something like that achievable? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am going to suggest you use the awk command. I will have a play and get back to you. Welcome it seems.

Comment: Yep RomanPerekhrest's solution works for me in OSX Terminal running Bash with the test data you have provided. He explains the key elements of the awk command well. You can look up the manual page for the awk command on the net. Better are web pages like [The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html). This page down at the moment, but likely up again later. If your doing more of this kind of work it is worth acquiring a basic understanding of how this command works and its options in my view. Quite powerful and particularly good for unusually formatted list files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short ***awk*** solution:

Let's say the file has content:

```
43718,0.0040389517\Am,-1.7885800013,-0.6239343718,-0.0040389517\\Versi
on=AM64L-G09RevD.01\State=13-AU\HF=-4237.9263963\S2=43.283985\S2-1=0.\
S2A=42.176337\RMSD=5.586e-09\RMSF=2.812e-05\Dipole=0.,0.,0.\Quadrupole
63732,-2.373882,2.364348\C,0,1.172319,-2.404467,3.15907\La,0,1.953277,
0.,0.\La,0,-1.953277,0.,0.\\Version=AM64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-AG\HF=-39
18.0496979\RMSD=3.915e-09\Dipole=0.,0.,0.\Quadrupole=12.1772596,-7.248
```

The command:

```
awk -v RS="\\" '$0~/^HF=/{sub("\n","",$0); print}' file
```

The output:

```
HF=-4237.9263963
HF=-39 18.0496979
```

---

- `-v RS="\\"` - considering `\` as record separator
- `$0~/^HF=/` - if a line starts with needed prefix `HF=`
- `sub("\n","",$0)` - removing possible newlines within a line

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice

```
grep -o 'HF=[^\\]*' file
```

`-o` returns only the matched part (and not the whole line).
`[^\\]` is a character class that excludes the backslash.

Comment: That works for the first example, but not for second, cause matched part is divided on two lines.

Comment: @AdamJaroš: that doesn't appear in your question. Post the correct data with the correct formatting and you will get correct answers.